# what is the max length of the query string supported by the "mobile" safari browser?

Tags: iphone

what is the max length of the query string supported by the "mobile" safari browser? i am working on an application where i have to append all the records from sqlite db to the remote database.i am using aspx to do so.The current query string length for one record comes upto 350 characters.is it possible for me to send about 200 records in that query string(70,000 characters).i have read that safari browser supports upto 80,000 characters.i wanted to know if it is the same for the mobile safari browser. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: POST allows you to send any amount of data you want. Why use GET and put it in the querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html), it's 80000 or more. However you will also have to ensure that your server that receives the request supports this. For instance if you connect to an Apache server, you might run into problems already at around 4000 characters.

Generally you should try to limit the length of your url. If you need to transmit a lot of data it's better to use http POST where the data is contained in the body instead of in the URL.

Comment: That site doesn’t seem to claim to have tested mobile browsers at all…